# Reporting service. Use the column as a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Im using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and I am creating a report let's call it "DataSet1" which will retrieve `Names`, `Address`, `ID No.`. My report has columns `Name`, `Address`, `ID No.` and `Names with same ID No.`.

*Question:* Can I use the `ID No.` column as a parameter of a separate query that will retrieve a result and display it to the `Names with same ID No.` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [drillthrough report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207031.aspx) by setting a click action on the table row, and pass the `ID No.` as a parameter to the other report. That report can have its own query where `ID No.` is a parameter to filter rows.

If you're looking to show the data in the *same* report I think you're better off just querying the data you want at once and grouping, e.g.:

```
SELECT m1.Name, m1.Address, m1.[ID No.], m2.Name
FROM   MyData m1
       JOIN MyData m2 ON m1.[ID No.] = m2.[ID No.] AND m1.Name <> m2.Name
```

Then group in SSRS on the `m1` columns and show `m2` as a list of subresults using an SSRS control of your choosing.

Comment: I need single row for Name for m1, what if there are multiple results Name from m2 that has duplicate ID no.?

Comment: Well, you tell me. What do *you* want in that case?